# How do i get the site name from a url in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using google custom search to retrieve images but I want to add `From:` + site name

I have the following which gives me the full url:

```
      var imgurl = item.link;
```

Which that is: `https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1012/1362641756_69b7f29427_b.jpg`

How do i only get the first part `https://c1.staticflickr.com/`

Those urls will be dynamic so i don't know if it will be `http` or `https`

Comment: try `console.log(window.location);` You will find everything you need in there, just target the properties you wish to use. `window.location.protocal` and `window.location.hostname` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: @NewToJS it isn't the url in the address bar but what I got from that variable `var imgurl = item.link;`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I read the question wrong. My apologies. Maybe regex will be good for this!

Comment: I already read that answer, this isn't a duplicate, will change the title

Comment: The answer marked as a duplicate could be used to answer your question. It will only require you to make a few minor changes.